# Array only contains last value added but count is still the same

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am parsing JSON and appending the data to an array, and while the array contains the correct number of elements, it is just the same element over and over, whatever the last one added was.  Here is the code I am using:

```
if (statusCode == 200) {
    do{
      let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)
      if let ns = json as? NSArray{
        for ns in ns{
          if let name = ns["name"] as?  String{
            if let number = ns["number"] as? Int{
              if let cn = ns["cyclenumber"] as? Int{
                if let url = ns["url"] as? String{
                  self.c.name = name
                  self.c.number = number
                  self.c.cycleNumber = cn
                  self.c.url = url
                  self.n.array.append(self.c)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }catch {
       print("Error with Json: \(error)")
   }

 }
```

When I print the array, it just prints however many elements were added, but they are all duplicates of the last element added.

Comment: Holy pyramid of doom batman...

Comment: Does `for ns in ns` compile at all?

Comment: I think it will work, but you won't be able to access the array called ns and therefore is very bad practice and quite confusing. (so is having 1 or 2 letter names, but that's a different issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep appending the sane instance - namely, `self.c`. Since the type of `c` is a `class`, not `struct`, no copying is going on; the same reference is added to the array over and over again.

You can fix this problem by making `c`'s type a `struct`, or by assigning a new `c` on each iteration of the loop:

```
if let url = ns["url"] as? String {
    var c = TypeOfC() // Make a new instance
    c.name = name
    c.number = number
    c.cycleNumber = cn
    c.url = url
    self.n.array.append(c)
}
```

Note that `c` is no longer a member of `self`. Since you are changing `c` inside a loop, making it a member was very likely a mistake in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Answer's already been given, but I thought I should clean up your code a bit :)

```
guard let data = data where statusCode == 200 else {
    return
}

do{
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:.AllowFragments)

    if let ns = json as? NSArray{
        for ns in ns{
            if let name = ns["name"] as? String, number = ns["number"] as? Int,
                cn = ns["cyclenumber"] as? Int, url = ns["url"] as? String{

                    self.c.name = name
                    self.c.number = number
                    self.c.cycleNumber = cn
                    self.c.url = url
                    self.n.array.append(self.c)
                }
            }
        }

}catch {
    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Newer to Swift, appreciate the help.